# Button requires 2 clicks to swap out div

Tags: javascript, toggle, visibility

I have a simple div swap out when the buttons are clicked. However, when the page first loads, it requires the user to click twice on the button for the function to work. After that everything works well. Any advice please?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2) {
        d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
        d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
        if (d2.style.display == "none") {
            d1.style.display = "none";
            d2.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            d1.style.display = "block";
            d2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

</script>




<style>
    #swapper-other {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: darkred;
        color: #fff;
        display: none;
    }

    #swapper-first {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        color: #444;
    }

</style>

 <div id="swapper-first">
    <p>
        <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('swapper-first','swapper-other')">(Swap Divs)</a>
    </p>


    <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
        This div displayed when the web page first loaded.
    </p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-other">
    <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('swapper-first','swapper-other')">(Swap Divs)</a>
    <p>
        This div displayed when the link was clicked.
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to detect styles on the way, you should use `getComputedStyle` method instead.

Below updated version of code with your example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    #swapper-other {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: darkred;
        color: #fff;
        display: none;
    }

    #swapper-first {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        color: #444;
    }

</style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2, e) {

        let d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
        let d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
        let computedStyleD1 = window.getComputedStyle(d1, null);
        let computedStyleD2 = window.getComputedStyle(d2, null);    
        if (computedStyleD2.display == "none") {             
            d1.style.display = "none";
            d2.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            d1.style.display = "block";
            d2.style.display = "none";
        }

      e.stopPropagation();         
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="swapper-first">
    <p>
        <a href='#' onclick="SwapDivsWithClick('swapper-first','swapper-other', event)">(Swap Divs)</a>
    </p>


    <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
        This div displayed when the web page first loaded.
    </p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-other">
    <a href='#' onclick="SwapDivsWithClick('swapper-first','swapper-other', event)">(Swap Divs)</a>
    <p>
        This div displayed when the link was clicked.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks pepsilike. Being a 'frontend' hacker its great to learn a bit of the real stuff at the backend. Thanks for the full code. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your css display values are not caught by the JS `d2.style.display`
Instead try the following

```
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2) {
    d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
    d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
    style = getComputedStyle(d2);
    if (style.display == "none") {
        d1.style.display = "none";
        d2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        d1.style.display = "block";
        d2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This will get the css at the moment of the call.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `console.log(d2.style.display);` just before the if it will show nothing (empty string), at least in my chrome. This is why it's not `= "none"`.
As a consequence `if (d2.style.display == "none")` won't evaluate to true.
Change to

```
if (d2.style.display != "block")
```

and it'll work!

Further investigations:

```
console.log("typeof d2.style.display: "+typeof(d2.style.display));
console.log("length of d2.style.display: "+d2.style.display.length);
// OUTPUT:
// typeof d2.style.display: string
// length of d2.style.display: 0
```

Even further investigations:
in css `display: none;` will result in a hidden div, but the value isn't set in js.
If I put anything like 'xyz' in `display: xyz;` it is shown, but the value isn't set in js.
If I write `display: 'none';` the div isn't hidden (of course), but the if evaluates...
Finally: There is no way I could make `console.log(d2.style.display);` show anything unless it's in quotes or set via javascript.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! This stuff is way over my head by I understand your reasoning.